# Ошибка при расконсервации данных

Tags: python, сериализация, десериализация, pickle

Пишу функцию для викторины. Мне нужно достать из законсервированного файла рекорды (только очки). Если файл пустой, я заполняю его числами 0, 1, 2, 3 и 4. При запуске получаю следующую ошибку:

```
File "D:/Работа/Python/quiz/main.py", line 91, in record
    first = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Вот часть кода функции:

```
def record(score, record_file):
    f = open(record_file, "wb+")
    try:
        first = pickle.load(f)
    except EOFError:
        pickle.dump(4, f)
        pickle.dump(3, f)
        pickle.dump(2, f)
        pickle.dump(1, f)
        pickle.dump(0, f)
        first = pickle.load(f)
    second = pickle.load(f)
    third = pickle.load(f)
    fourth = pickle.load(f)
    fifth = pickle.load(f)
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема? Я подозреваю, что неправильно консервирую данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически, в `pickle` файл можно дописывать данные если открывать его в режиме `r+b` или `ab`:

```
def add_to_pickle(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)

add_to_pickle(1, filename)
add_to_pickle("a string", filename)
add_to_pickle([1, 2, 3], filename)
```

но читать из такого файла надо будет аккуратно - мы не знаем когда файл закончится:

```
def read_from_pickle(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break
```

---

пример:

```
In [29]: [x for x in read_from_pickle(filename)]
Out[29]: [1, 'a string', [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

**UPDATE:** лучше и безопаснее накапливать данные в список или словарь и перезаписывать pickle файл обновленным словарем - тогда мы знаем, что в pickle файле всего один объект.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но если dump перезаписывает содержимое каждый раз, как дальше консервировать данные в тот же файл?

Comment: @Liquid, накапливать данные в словарь и перезаписывать файл новым словарем

Comment: *Каждый вызов команды pickle.dump(obj, f) перезаписывает содержимое файла f.* - это не так.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, да, в общем случае все зависит от режима открытия файла. Исправил ответ

Comment: Странно. Ведь ошибка возникает при первой же попытке достать данные из законсервированного файла (first = pickle.load(f)), а не из-за того, что я пытаюсь считать больше, чем есть. То есть файл f остаётся полностью пустым после 5 вызовов команды dump.

Comment: @Liquid, ошибка возникает потому, что при режиме открытия файла `"wb+"` - указатель находится в конце файла - для того, чтобы __дописывать__ в конец файла. Если хотите читать из такого файла - надо открыть его в режиме `"rb"` или передвинуть указатель в начало файла